# Xamarin Code Behind Missing After Updating Nuget Package

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget, visual-studio-2019

Today, I updated a nuget package, and after this, my code behind for several content views was missing.  I can't find the missing files in finder or in my solution.  Using Visual Studio 2019 for Mac.

Tried:

Clean and Rebuild, unload, and restart Visual studio and Machine.

Comment: Need more info, what nuget package do you think did this? Are you using source control? Also, you might try here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/mac/

Comment: I installed Newtonsoft.Json.  I was not using source control, but believe me I am now.

Comment: That package has over 930M downloads, I'm sure if it was deleting code people would be in a uproar. Something else is amiss here.

Comment: This isnt the first time ive had this happen.  My code behind will just appear in my android package or else where.

Comment: @mxmissile you mean that you update Newtonsoft.Json, then your project code will be deleted? I have never encounter such  a problem.

Comment: Not just when updating this package.  I will just be working on something and run a build, all of a sudden my viewmodels are moved on the solution tree to a different folder.  Could this be a corrupt version of the visual studio app? Ive seen other people have this problem with mac.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs-2019-for-mac-losinghiding-files/875292

@CherryBu-MSFT

Comment: @Bloodred566 Seems that you have one solution?

Answer (score 0):

See fix from VS Community Boards: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs-2019-for-mac-losinghiding-files/875292